# Properties of subspaces of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $V$ be subspaces of the vector space $W$. Show that $$U+V=W \text{ and } U\cap V=\{0\}$$ holds if and only if for every vector $w$, there exists unique vectors $u\in U$ and $v\in V$ such that $w=u+v$.

---

Suppose $U+V=W$ and $U\cap V=\{0\}$, so $0\in U$ and $0\in V$. If $w_{1}\in W$ then $w_{1}=u_{1}+v_{1}$. Now suppose $w_{1} = u_{2}+v_{2}$ where $u_{2}\in U$ and $v_{2}\in V$ then to show $u_{1}$ and $v_{1}$ are unique we must show $u_{1}=u_{2}$ and $v_{1}=v_{2}$. Here is where I don't really know how to proceed in this part.

Suppose for every $w\in W$, there exists unique $u\in U$ and $v\in V$ such that $w=u+v$. We can therefore write $W = \{w=u+v\colon u\in U,\, v\in V\} = U+V.$ I'm not really sure how to deduce that $U\cap V=\{0\}$ in this part, any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Here is where I don't really know how to proceed in this part." If $u_1+v_1=u_2+v_2$ then $u_1-u_2=v_2-v_1\in U\cap V=0$.

"I'm not really sure how to deduce that..." If $u\in U\cap V$ then  in particular $u\in W$ and $u=u+0=0+u$ implies $u=0$ by uniqueness.

Comment: Hi, for the first part I understand you are trying to find a contradiction and that $u_1-u_2=v_2-v_1=0$ and certainly $0\in U\cap V$, so where is the contradiction? Also I don't really understand what you mean by $U\cap V=0$ since $U\cap V$ is a set and $0$ is a number? For the second part how does $u=u+0=0+u$ imply that $u=0$?

Comment: @user2850514 hi, I am not trying to find a contradiction. I just use to hypothesis to conclude that $u_1=u_2$ etc.; $U\cap V=0$ is frequently used notation for $U\cap V=\{0\}$ (so what is the difference between a set and a number? formally everything in math is a set!). It follows from uniqueness!

Comment: Ok for the first part we have deduced that $0\in U\cap V$ however we haven't shown that's the only element so why is this satisfactory? For the second part, what is uniqueness, I don't understand what you mean by that. You mean to say that for any $x$ we can conclude that if $x=x+0=0+x$ then $x=0$? This is clearly false because then you could take $x=5$ and you would have $5=0$.. ?

Comment: @user2850514 uniqueness is a property of vector spaces, say a vector space has two additive identities $0$ and $0'$ then $$0'=0'+0=0+0'=0$$ so they must be unique

Comment: @user2850514 if $u=0$ then since $u\in U\cap V$ and $u$ was arbitrary then $U\cap V=\{0\}$

Comment: I don't understand how you make the final equality that $0+0'=0$, how do you know $0'=0$?

Comment: Let's keep it related to the question. So I completely understand that we can write $u$ in two other ways, namely $u+0$ and $0+u$ thus forming the equality $u=u+0=0+u$ but how do we then conclude that $u=0$, we aren't given any more information..

Comment: @user2850514 if $0$ and $0'$ are both additive identities then $0'=0'+0$ since $0$ is an additive identity, and in a vector space we have commutativity so $0'+0=0+0'$, and since $0'$ is an additive identity we have $0+0'=0$ $$\tag*{$\tiny\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: @user2850514: every $w\in W$ can be written in a unique way as $w=u+v$. now  in our case $u=u+0=0+u\in U\cap V$ with $u,0\in U\cap V$, this gives $u=0$ by uniqueness!

Comment: In the question however $u$ is not an additive identity, it is just an arbitrary element of the set.

Comment: @user2850514 my comment pointed out a proof of the uniqueness of a vector space which you didn't know about, i didn't address the 'u=u+0=0+u' which Laters just explained in his recent comment

Comment: @Laters I feel like you're assuming that we already know that $U\cap V=\{0\}$ but this is what I am trying to deduce! I don't know how many elements are in the set and I don't know what each of the elements are, so there is no way to conclude $u=0$ without that information! (Unless of course I am wrong, which is more likely).

Comment: The statement $u=u+0=0+u$ is true for any $u$, for example let $u=5$ then $5=5+0=0+5$ which is completely true so I don't understand how you can deduce that $u=0$, surely $u$ can be any number since this will always be true.

Comment: @user2850514 I think I can't really help you on this, you somehow have to convince yourself (I am not assuming $U\cap V=0$ of course). One last try $u=u_1+v_1=u_2+v_2$ with $u_1=v_2=u\in U\cap V$, $v_1=u_2=0\in U\cap V$. This gives me $u_1=u_2$ **by uniqueness**. Also considering a field as a vector space over itself is here not very enlightening, as it has dimension $1$, $U\cap V=0$ here implies $U=0$ or $V=0$. You must understand how the relation among the spaces is.

Comment: Sorry, I think that last response has confused me even more. I understand we can write $u=u_{1}+v_{1}=u_{2}+v_{2}$ but how do we know that $u_{1}=v_{2}=u$ and that $v_{1}=u_{2}=0$?

Comment: @user2850514 I am defining the $u_1,v_1$, etc. by this equation (I understand your confusion.), meaning I am just introducing this notation in order to make you less confused, but I apparently failed

Comment: Is there another way to prove my question because I just don't understand this way at all?

Comment: @user2850514 I don't think that there is an essentially distinct way to prove this, let me give you an advice: forget about this for some hours, go to sleep or whatever, and come back. You somehow have to think very hard about what uniqueness of the decomposition means: it says that any element of $W$ can be written uniquely as the sum of an element of $U$ and one of $V$. If you take any $w\in W$ then you have $w=0+w=w+0$ but you cannot conclude $w=0$, **the reason being that $w$ need not be in $U$ nor $V$!** (you would need both! in my argument $u\in U\cap V$ **by assumption**)

Comment: I haven't actually come back to this problem however I shall do soon.